# Laser diode stand-in for ESD destructive testing

Tags: esd, laser-diode

Is there any component with similar ESD sensitivities as laser diodes but with lower cost that can be used as a stand-in for destructive testing of ESD protection circuits? Should I just use MOSFET gates?

Comment: just use FETs.. and hope the design is non-destructive

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to find some other device that you can confident will be damaged by the same stress levels that would damage your laser. Why not just monitor the delivered pulse with a (fast) oscilloscope and guess at some voltage or current level that you can accept.

Comment: I guess a similarly sized LED would be pretty similar

Comment: @ThePhoton I suppose I could do that so long as I continue to have access to a high bandwidth oscilloscope.